# App is crashing while trying to debug it [corruption heap]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, crash

I have the following problem:

I have a command line application.When I run it from command line it works fine, but when I try to debug it I got the following message:

*Windows has triggered a breakpoint in orb_app.exe. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in orb_app.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.*

The application is using omniORB implementation of CORBA protocol to interact with remote app. 
Compiler: Microsoft C++ 2003
OS : Windows 2003

What can be the reason that I cannot debug my app?

Comment: An application may run just fine while still corrupting the heap. Why do you say you can't debug it? Have you tried tracking down and fixing the heap corruption? If the corruption is happening in a DLL that isn't yours, have you checked to see if if you're running it the same way with the debugger that you are without it (same command line arguments, same working directory)? Is it possible you're providing a string that's too long to one of your DLLs? I had that happen with a corba implementation once, it was writing off the end of a string because the hostname I gave it was too long.

Comment: Are you running a debug or release build from the command line? the debug build contains all sorts of checks, which are designed to detect heap corruptions and such. In release builds you still have the same bugs, but you might get (un)lucky if your particular bug doesn't damage data in a way that crashes your program. So, if you see this error in the debugger - you have a bug. Not seeing it in release just means it's hidden well - for the current version of your code and data.

Comment: When I try to debug it I got heap corruption on the CORBA library Send method. But cannot identify the reason as it can crash rigth after the 1-st request and the next time it can be 2nd or 3rd request. I used the same arguments in debuger and when I run it from command line without debugger.

Comment: I use debug build. I run it from command line and in debuger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved. The option /MDd was used instead of /MD to generate the full debug info.